# Collapsing unused space in CSS Grid two-column layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a two-column layout that's relatively easy to achieve with floats or absolutely placed content. The main column is 65% wide and the secondary column is 30% wide. Just to keep things simple, let's say an article consists of headings and paragraphs, and a blockquote that can be arbitrarily floated to the right anywhere within the article. Here's an example:

https://codepen.io/dalton/pen/MzyXmX

I tried to accomplish something similar using CSS Grid layout, but I'm getting extra spaces when the sidebar content is taller than the immediately preceding main content. Here's my example:

https://codepen.io/dalton/pen/aQNGga

Here's a screenshot illustrating the gap when using CSS Grid:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's a relevant markup example:

```
<main>
  <h1>Article Title</h1>
  <p>Aliquam lobortis. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor.Etiam vitae tortor. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris.</p>
  <blockquote>Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.</blockquote>
  <p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci.</p>
</main>
```

Here's the CSS required to accomplish this layout with floats:

```
h1, h2, p {
  width: 65%;
}

blockquote {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}
```

And here's the CSS I've tried to accomplish the layout with CSS Grid:

```
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65% 30%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1, h2, p {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

blockquote {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

Just to be clear, I don't want to create a two-column layout with DIVs. The blockquote (or other arbitrary sidebar content) must be placed relative to content in the main column.

Comment: The premise of your title -- *...collapsing unused space...* -- is a bit off. The (row) space you're referring to isn't unused. It's being used by the text in the second column, so it cannot be collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the element to span different rows instead of only one:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65% 30%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p, h1, h2, h2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

blockquote {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: span 6; /*added this*/
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Article Title</h1>
  
  <p>Aliquam lobortis. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor.Etiam vitae tortor. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris.</p>

  <p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci.</p>
  
   <p>Aliquam lobortis. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor.Etiam vitae tortor. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris.</p>
  <blockquote>
Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.
</blockquote>
  <p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci.</p>
<p>Aliquam lobortis. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor.Etiam vitae tortor. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris.</p>
<p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci.</p>
<h2>Another Headline</h2>
<p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci.</p>
<p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci.</p>

</main>
```

Comment: That looks good for this precise example, but has problems when you have additional elements in the sidebar. See what happened when I placed another blockquote after the next paragraph: https://imgur.com/a/IIVwjkN